# SQL Pivot table CTE and Order producing Null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, common-table-expression

I'm trying to get the following to work,  I'm new to Pivot tables,  I thought I had it but I get a lot of null values.   What am I missing?  Also where can I insert the ORDER BY clause to sort on NUM.

```
 with cte_Inst as
 (

    SELECT     Inst.Num, Branch.BranchNum, 
    inst.Name as 'InstName', Center.ProfitCenter, 
    Center.plant, Branch.Idx, Inst.Enable,Inst.BranchBilling, mainframe.Name as 'Host', center.Name as 'Center'
    FROM         Center RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      mainframe ON Center.Idx = mainframe.CenterIdx RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      DB ON mainframe.Idx = DB.MainframeIdx RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      Inst ON DB.DBIdx = Inst.DBIdx RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      Branch ON Inst.Idx = Branch.InstIdx
    where BranchNum = 999999
    --order by Num, BranchNum 

  )

select num, PRB575  as 'PRB575', PRB576 as 'PRB576', PRB577 as 'PRB577', PRB578 as 'PRB578', PRB579 as'PRB579',PRB580 as'PRB580', PRB572 as 'PRB572', PRB573 as 'PRB573',PRB851 as'PRB851', PRB581 as 'PRB581', PRB582 as 'PRB582',PRB583 as'PRB583'
From 
(                     
            SELECT     InputCounts.Count as 'Total', InputCounts.DateTime, cte_Inst.num, --cte_Inst.InstName,  
        InputDesc.ShortName,   
                              Material.FoundationMaterialNumber, cte_inst.host,  cte_Inst.Center   
        FROM        cte_Inst 
                    left OUTER JOIN InputCounts on InputCounts.BranchIdx = cte_Inst.Idx 
                    left outer join PhysicalSource on InputCounts.PhysicalSourceIdx = PhysicalSource.Idx  
                    left outer join InputDesc ON  InputDesc.Idx = inputcounts.inputdescidx 
                    left OUTER JOIN Material ON InputDesc.MaterialIdx = Material.Idx
                    WHERE     ( (cte_Inst.Enable ='true')   
                              and (InputCounts.DateTime > '2017-03-28')
                              and FoundationMaterialNumber in  ('PRB575','PRB576','PRB577','PRB578','PRB579','PRB580','PRB572','PRB573','PRB851','PRB581','PRB582','PRB583')
                              ))
                      As SourceDataTable
Pivot
(
Max(Total) for FoundationMaterialNumber in (PRB575, PRB576, PRB577,PRB578,PRB579,PRB580,PRB572,PRB573,PRB851,PRB581,PRB582,PRB583))
as pivottable
```

The Original Data Set Before the Pivot
[image: Before Pivot]

After Pivot
[image: After Pivot]

Comment: Remove unneeded columns from the select list in the derived table that is the pivot source.

Comment: At the very end.

Comment: Thank you that fixed it!